# Firebase Cloud Messaging Not working with message topic

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

After updating Firebase to the newest version, sending cloud messages through "topic" does not work.

I am wondering which update caused the failure of sending push notifications using "Topic". What should I do to make it work?

[image]

Comment: Did you figure out what was wrong? This suddenly happened to me as well.

Comment: Did you figure out what was wrong?